# MQTT ISSUE: Broker closing connection as i send connect packet

Tags: c, mqtt, gprs

Its my first post here. Correct me if im wrong

I'm using free scale controller with G620 module for connecting to server.
I started to implement MQTT client.

The communication with G620 GPRS module through UART.
Through AT commands i connected to the MQTTbroker.
As soon as i sent the connect packet, broker closing the connection. 
Need help or suggestion.

The connect packet is: `{ 0x10,0x12,0x00,0x04,M,Q,T,T,0x04,0x00,0x3C,0x00,0x00,0x06,Z,1,2,1,2,3
}`

Comment: Are there any logs from the broker that may explain why it's closing the connection?

Comment: What broker and version are you using? Does it support MQTT v3.1.1?

Comment: im using mosquitto broker ...... It supports the version. My application same developed MQTT client app (in java i guess) and its working fine......the same way i need to develop in RTOS.

Comment: Im unable to find out Y its closing the connection.......... Im trying to solve the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two scenarios the server is disconnecting you as per MQTT Protocol.
1. If you are violating protocol format
2. If the timeout of the connection is exceeded

**Reasons for Protocol Violation termination:**
- You might have wrongly framed out some protocol bytes. Cross verify with the protocol [document](http://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v3.1.1/os/mqtt-v3.1.1-os.pdf).
- You might be already connected and trying to connect again. Check for server side logs if you have access.
- As you are sending the frame through UART, you might have used a for loop to send the bytes. If the for loop counter is based from "strlen(Connectpacket)", you will not get the exact count as "strlen" will terminate after 0x00. So the server will receive half packet and disconnects you for violation.

Your protocol seems to be invalid,
0x10 - MQTT Control Packet type
0x12 - Remaining Length
0x00 - Length MSB
0x04 - Length LSB
M
Q
T
T - Protocol Name
0x04 - Protocol Level
0x00 - Connect Flags
0x3C - Keep Alive MSB
0x00 - Keep Alive LSB
**0x00,0x06,Z,1,2,1,2,3** - What are there bytes used for? Cross verify with protocol document.

Set clean session bit as 1. Set keep alive for 0x00 MSB 0x3C LSB.